# Codepage on Pushbullet API (REST)

Tags: pushbullet

Which codepage does Pushbullet run on the REST API? I have difficulty with Nordic characters (æøåÆØÅ), I have tried several different ways to format the JSON, but still the characters is wierd.

I am calling the API via Powershell "Invoke-RestMethod"

Any help will appreciated

Answer (score 0):

We use Unicode.  The JSON format requires unicode characters: http://www.json.org/  I'd recommend UTF8 as the encoding of choice, because it's least likely to cause problems.